# Google Sheets pretty formulas formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm finding these increasingly harder to manipulate.

is there another way that avoids using the formula bar?

Some text editor that provides indentation perhaps?

[image: crazy long formula]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press:

**Ctrl + Enter** on Windows

**⌘ + Enter** on a Mac

inside the formula editor bar to add new lines to your formulas in order to make them more readable.

---

To **comment** inside formulas, you can use [N()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357?hl=en).

For example:

```
=SUM(A1:A)+N("This is a comment.")
```

this will give exactly the same result as:

```
=SUM(A1:A)
```

**Note** that:

```
N("This is a comment")
```

returns **0**.

If you want to avoid that, you can use `T(N("comment"))` which acts like a blank string.

**Example:**

[image: example]

Comment: thanks - do you know a way of commenting inside formulas?
can indenting work this way?

Comment: was going add the N function to my answer, but just take into account that the N function as the docs refer: *"returns the argument provided as a number."*, when you put text into it it will return 0, meaning it is the same as `sum(A1:A) + 0`

Comment: @nabais yes, thanks for the comment! I elaborated further :)

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull for documentation purposes, could you accept the answer that helped you the most ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Marios busy week!

Just to recap. That is an interesting way to do a comment... but you know currently of no (3rd party perhaps) text editors with debugging?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull Hi! I don't think there is an editor like that. Unfortunately..

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best answer, but as I had the same problem before, what I do is copy the formula to a text editor (or pastebin), ident the formula, select all and then repaste in the google sheets formula. If pasted it will have a line break, like this:

```
={
ARRAYFORMULA(somecomplicatedstuffhere) ,
ARRAYFORMULA(moreformulashere) 
}
```

Also, if you are inside the cell, you can add a newline this way:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Mac/ Linux: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: thanks - do you know a way of commenting inside formulas?
can indenting work this way?